# Is this suggested solution for the below mentioned erratum correct?

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

5-2.Do a topological sort of the following graph G

[image]

This problem is from "The Algorithm Design Manual (2nd Edition)" by Steven Skiena.
 Since, this graph is not a DAG topological sorting can't be done.
In the errata list for this book it is suggested to reverse the edge (F,H)
but this will make the vertex "H" unreachable. Then how this [solution](http://www.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu/algowiki/index.php?title=TADM2E_5.2&action=edit) is possible 
"A, B, D, E, C, H, G, I, J, F".

Comment: You mean `H` becomes unreachable?

Comment: The solution is valid because all predecessors of H (none!) are mentioned before H.

Comment: ya i made mistake. That should be "H" instead of "F".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is valid since `H` has no successors that mentioned before `H` and no predecessors that are mentioned after `H`.

It's not any stranger than the fact that the graph

```
A <- B -> C
```

(where `B` is "unreachable") can be topologically sorted as

```
B, A, C
```

Comment: when i have solved the above question i got this answer A,B,D,E,C,G,F,I,J,H. here i have just placed H in the last because it is not violating the rule that all the predecessors of a vertex should be processed first. is my answer valid?

Comment: Hmm.. No, because `H` would then come after `G`. You should be ok if you put `H` first. (In fact you just showed that my answer was incomplete. Answer updated.)

Comment: would yu like to verify my new answer "A, B, D, E, H, G, I, J, C, F".  Thanks in advance